# Why SVG rotate about a point formula is reverse of normal formula？

Tags: math, svg

I am reading `SVG` Essentials, at chapter 6, it talk about the rotate transform. It says

> rotate(angle, centerX, centerY) is equal to translate(centerX, centerY) rotate(angle) translate(-centerX, -centerY)

But What I learn before to calc this problem is first make point A(x,y) to A(x - centerX, y - centerY), then rotate, then add centerX, centerY back.

Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32376643/4263793) says.

I try to review some linear algebra knowledge but still can't figure what's the different.

Can any one tell me the why this happen?

Kindly guide me why `svg` add-rotate-sub and normal is sub-rotate-add?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. In SVG specification, the order of transformations is applied from right to left, so it matches your intuition:

```
1) translate(-centerX, -centerY)
2) rotate(angle) 
3) translate(centerX, centerY)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18587460/11292489) for more details.